# unable to parse .conf file using java

Tags: java, parsing, text, brackets

```
<TF_INFO_START>
<TF_HOST>`TF_IN`
<TF_ID>`3219`
<TF_INFO_END>
<SF_INFO>
<SF_NAME>`JOHN`<IP>`10.110.12.12`<SF_PORT>`9101`
<END_SF_INFO>

<COMPONENT_START_TAG>
<COMPONENT_NAME>`AISMOD`<PATH>`AISPATH`<TYPE>`U`<M>`main`
<COMPONENT_END_TAG>
```

I want to parse the above test.conf file and display each parameter in the log file.I have tried parsing it like

```
Properties configFile = new Properties();
    configFile.load(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/JOHN/Desktop/test.conf"));
    String foo = configFile.getProperty("TF_HOST");
```

I couldn't get value of TF_HOST and other parameters.I get null result..

Can anyone help me in parsing the above file content

Comment: It's not entirely clear what format your configuration file is in. Based on your code snippet, it looks like you're using Java's Properties configuration file format, but your example configuration file is a little confusing. Does `test.conf` contain your example config verbatim, or are the brackets/backticks supposed to indicate example data? Can you provide a configuration file you want to parse and the expected configFile representation?

Answer (score 1):

Write your conf file as 
key=value
then using ResourceBundle you can easily read the file.
Like

---

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getundle("com.demo.conf");//path for conf       file in my case it is in com.demo package
String value = rb.getString(key);
```

Comment: Hi Shahid,Sorry i couldn't get the value..I tried the below..   ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("C:/Users/JOHN/Desktop/test.conf",en_US);
String HOST= rb.getString("TF_HOST");             System.out.println(HOST);

Comment: Ravi, change extension of your file to .properies instead of .conf. As resource bundle appends .properties extension by default. So finally t will look like ResourceBundle.getBundle("C:/Users/JOHN/Desktop/test",en_US);